# Error when trying to use Simple-JNDI

Tags: java, unit-testing, jndi, hsqldb, in-memory-database

For unit testing purposes, I'm trying to set up JNDI to connect to a HSQLDB without  using Tomcat. To do this I am using [Simple-JNDI](https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI) and following this [website](http://%20http://www.briskbee.com/2010/07/setting-up-datasource-in-jndi.html).

So first I created a class that will initialize the a JNDI Data Source:

```
import org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource;    
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class JndiDataSource {
    public void Initialize() throws NamingException {
        // Create initial context
        System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.osjava.sj.MemoryContextFactory");
        System.setProperty("org.osjava.sj.jndi.shared", "true");
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

        ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env/jdbc");

        // Construct DataSource
        JDBCDataSource ds = new JDBCDataSource();
        ds.setDatabase("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb");
        ds.setUser("SA");
        ds.setPassword("");

        // Put datasource in JNDI context
        ic.bind("java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDS", ds);
    }
}
```

Then in a unit test I'm calling `Initialize()` and just attempting to lookup the Data Source.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;    
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class JndiDataSourceTest {
    @Test
    public void testInitialize() throws NamingException {
        JndiDataSource jds = new JndiDataSource();
        jds.Initialize();

        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)ic.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDS");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to debug this unit test it fails on the lookup, `(DataSource)ic.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDS");` The debugger says,

`javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDS`

So the question is, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Very rarely touch any JNDI, but if remember there are still some configurations need to be managed on the application server to allow the datasource name to be valid/introduced.

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone: With Simple-JNDI, no application server is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it's a simple typo - IMHO it should be org.osjava.sj.**memory**.MemoryContextFactory

Comment: That's what it was in the link i posted, but for me the memory directory was missing from the simple-jndi jar.

Comment: Looks like I had the wrong maven dependency. Was using this `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.h-thurow/simple-jndi/0.17.0`. Changed to this `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/simple-jndi/simple-jndi/0.11.4.1` and it seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Simple-JNDI up to 0.18.1 is that org.osjava.sj.MemoryContextFactory does not take system properties into account. Therefore with every call to

```
new InitialContext()
```

a new MemoryContext is initialized which does not share anything with a previous initialized one.

I changed this behaviour with 0.18.2. Until then there are two solutions.

**First**:

Put a jndi.properties in your classpath with this content:

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.osjava.sj.MemoryContextFactory
org.osjava.sj.jndi.shared = true
```

So you can dispense with system properties.

**Second**

A more error prone method. Use the constructor, that takes an environment configuration:

```
InitialContext(Hashtable<?, ?> environment)
```

Everytime you instantiate a new InitialContext you must provide the constructor with this environment:

```
    System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.osjava.sj.MemoryContextFactory");

    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put("org.osjava.sj.jndi.shared", "true");

    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(env);

    ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env/jdbc");

    JDBCDataSource ds = new JDBCDataSource();
    ds.setDatabase("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb");
    ds.setUser("SA");
    ds.setPassword("");

    ic.bind("java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDS", ds);

    // And elsewhere

    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put("org.osjava.sj.jndi.shared", "true");
    InitialContext ic2 = new InitialContext(env);
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ic2.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDS");
    assertNotNull(dataSource);
```

I would also advise to set

```
jndi.syntax.direction = left_to_right
jndi.syntax.separator = /
```

Simple-JNDI > 0.11.4.1 has many advantages. See [here](https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI).